# How to connect to Graphql server using Ember-Apollo?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, graphql, apollo, ember-cli

I am working with a full stack GraqlQL based application. The server is working fine and now I need to try out the first queries and mutations on the client side. For some reason, the "monitoring" route, and everything that follows it, is not displayed. Below I will show the files that I have edited or created.

items.graphql:

```
query {
  items {
    _id
    name
  }
}
```

environment.js:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(environment) {
  let ENV = {
    apollo: {
      apiURL: 'http://localhost:5000/graphql'
    },
    modulePrefix: 'client',
    environment,
    rootURL: '/',
    locationType: 'auto',
    EmberENV: {
      FEATURES: {
        //
      },
      EXTEND_PROTOTYPES: {
        Date: false
      }
    },

    APP: {
      //
    }
  };

  if (environment === 'development') {
    //
  }

  if (environment === 'test') {
    ENV.locationType = 'none';

    ENV.APP.LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION = false;
    ENV.APP.LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS = false;

    ENV.APP.rootElement = '#ember-testing';
    ENV.APP.autoboot = false;
  }

  if (environment === 'production') {
    //
  }

  return ENV;
};
```

monitoring.js (route):

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import { queryManager } from 'ember-apollo-client';
import query from 'client/gql/items.graphql';

export default Route.extend({
  apollo: queryManager(),

  model() {
    return this.apollo.watchQuery({ query }, 'items');
  }
});
```

monitoring.hbs:

```
<h3>Monitoring</h3>

<div>
  {{#each model as |item|}}
    <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
  {{/each}}
</div>

{{outlet}}
```

Thank you for attention!

I see this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: fetch is not defined - maybe your browser targets are not covering everything you need?
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this variant of graphql, but what's the type of 'model'? Is it an array or object? If you add {{log model}} it'll print to the console

Comment: It does'nt work even after i commented this block in the template

Comment: What doesn't work? Did you log? Can you share the output?

Comment: model() {
    // let variables = { id: params.id };
    console.log(model.toJSON());
    return this.apollo.watchQuery({ query }, 'items');
  }
// does'nt help

Comment: I meant log in the template to see what your model hook is returning. Keep the route as is :)

Comment: Does;nt help/ I see this error: "Uncaught (in promise) Error: fetch is not defined - maybe your browser targets are not covering everything you need?"

Comment: oh! no `fetch` is interesting. are you running in a server-side-rendered environment or just the browser (modern browsers have fetch) -- which browser are you using (and version?)

Comment: The browser is Firefox 81 64, ubuntu. It's a single page app using ember-cli. The server and client are in different folders

Comment: Checked in chrome, and the same error

Comment: being in different folders doesn't mean that there is no server-side-rendering. maybe install ember-fetch (fetch polyfill for environments that don't have fetch (like node)) and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to fix two things.
First is to put this in ember-cli-build.js:

```
'ember-fetch': {
  preferNative: true
}
```

And fix the route file:

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import { queryManager } from 'ember-apollo-client';
import query from 'client/gql/queries/items.graphql';

export default Route.extend({
  apollo: queryManager(),

  async model() {
    let queryResults = await this.apollo.watchQuery({ query }, 'items');
    return Object.values(queryResults);
  }
});
```